# Where can I find an auto click program for my mouse on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mouse, automation, accessibility

I have carpal tunnel from typing and clicking my mouse.

I have found many programs that auto click the mouse button in windows but none for Mac OS X.

Does anyone know where I can find a program like this for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4):

How about the "mouse keys" option in the Universal Access pane of the System Preferences app? There's more info on Apple's page about [physical and motor accessibility](http://www.apple.com/accessibility/macosx/physical.html) options for Mac OS X.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of web browsing, a macro recorder like [iMacros for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) or [iMacros for Chrome](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/chrome/) will also help to reduce the # of clicks. Both addons are free and open source.

You can use them to record standard operations such as login, form filling or drilling down to a certain feature/page once, and then trigger the replay of these so called "macros" with only *one* mouse click or keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched from windows to osx and had the same need.

http://dwellclick.com/ does exactly what you want.

There's a free trial and it's $15.

Answer (score 0):

For those using macOS 10.15 or later, you can use this one that I made after I couldn't find one that also works on that version.

[AutoClicker](https://autoclicker.focux.dev/)